# Program Gives An Error Every Time After Working Once

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to implement my own array using pointers in C++. I'm using Visual Studio. I'm relatively new to C++, so if there is something obvious that I'm missing bear with me. But when I run it the first time, it works as intended. However, the next time I run it, I get one of two errors. One of the errors is

```
Unable To Start Program, Access Denied.
"the path of the file"

Access Is Denied
```

The other one that comes up rarely is

```
main.cpp has triggered a breakpoint
```

I think it has something to do with a wrong use of pointers, however that doesn't explain why it works the first time. Here is the code:

In `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "linked_list.hpp"
#include "trie.hpp"
#include "stack.hpp"
#include "queue.hpp"
#include "array.hpp"

int main() {
    data_structures::array arr(5);
    arr.set(4, 1);
    int fourth_index = arr.get(4);
    std::cout << fourth_index;
}
```

In `array.hpp`:

```
#pragma once

namespace data_structures {
    class array {
    private:
        int* start;
    public:
        array(int size) {
            start = new int(0);

            for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
                *(start + i) = 0;
            }
        }
    public:
        void set(int index, int val) {
            if (index == 0) {
                start = new int(val);
            } else {
                *(start + index) = val;
            }
        }
        int get(int index) {
            return *(start + index);
        }
    };
}
```

The first time, I get the correct output:

```
1
```

Then the next time I get the error I stated above.

Comment: `start = new int(0)` allocates memory for a single `int`. `*(start + i)` then exhibits undefined behavior for any `i != 0`, by way of accessing an index out of bounds.

Comment: The access denied error is likely to be caused by antivirus software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you must be right! It is a memory issue and the error message "main.cpp has triggered a breakpoint" on windows indicates corruption of the heap in this case! I didn't have access to the hpp files you used apart from array.hpp

Let's start with some memory issues that your code is making

1. While initializing your array you are only initializing a single integer. But you need multiple integers in the array when you say want an array of size 5, you need to declare 5 integers. So you should declare an entire memory space for that. I am using malloc for this.

```
int* start = (int *)malloc(size*sizeof(int))
```

Secondly in your code for set there is a logical error that would change your start pointer from the original array which should not be happening. Instead you should just change the value at start.

```
*start = val;
```

Comment: _"the error message "main.cpp has triggered a breakpoint" on windows indicates corruption of the heap"_ Not necessarily but it does seem likely here. Note that switching from `new` to `malloc` is a backwards step in C++.

Comment: I understand that switching from new to malloc doesn't make sense, but it makes sense for the context of the question, if he were to use ```new int[5]``` he doesn't need to use a new class to simulate the array. He can directly use that in place of his class.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this malloc() function. I'll read up on it a little. But how come it works the first time, but then starts to error? Great answer anyways.

Comment: @naivecoder I'm not following you. `new int[size]` would be a drop-in replacement for your suggestion of `(int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int))`. Who said anything about classes or "simulating an array"? What does that mean?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings since he is trying to create a class that simulates an array creating an array inside the class doesn't make sense in terms of the simulation from a C++ perspective. He can directly use the new int[5] in place of his array class itself. But with the malloc he gets a chance to see what an array looks like under the hood.

Comment: @naivecoder Using `malloc` doesn't accomplish that. It simply uses the C approach to memory management. Please do not teach it in C++.

Answer (score 6):

Try changing this line:

```
start = new int(0);
```

to:

```
start = new int[size];
```

new int(0) is initializing "start" as a pointer to just one int with a value of 0. Instead, you need to allocate the memory necessary to hold your array. I suspect you're running into issues because you're writing into memory that you haven't allocated yet.

As a side note, make sure to add a destructor and free your memory.